# Content picker umbraco

Tags: umbraco

Have two docTypes one with a rich text editor and the other contentpicker.

Need any page that uses the contentpicker doctype to import content from the rich text editor on the other docType pages.

I can get the id of the page but not sure how to target the content in the editor

```
@Umbraco.Field("namedContentPicker")
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to get the value of the richtext editor of the node that is linked in the content picker?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use Umbraco.Field for that. Instead, do something like this:

```
@{var namedContent = Umbraco.TypedContent(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("namedContentPicker"))
var namedContentRte = namedContent.GetPropertyValue("richTextAliasHere")}
```

Comment: I think  you mean GetPropertyValue